# MySQL select group of columns AS one alias

Tags: mysql, select

**I have a table similar to this:**

```
ID    | Player1 | Player2 | Player3 | Player4 | Player5 | Player6 | Place
==============================================================================
1     | Greg    |  NULL   |  Mike   |  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   | Rockford
2     | NULL    |  Lisa   |  NULL   |  JEFF   |  NULL   |  NULL   | Peoria
```

**The output I want would be:**

```
Place    | Players
=====================
Rockford | Greg, Mike
Peoria   | Lisa, Jeff
```

**What I tried:**

I tried using CONCAT in my SELECT statement, but it seems like that is maybe a sloppy way of doing it.

Is there a better way to select the players where Player1, Player2, etc IS NOT NULL, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `concat_ws`:

```
select place, concat_ws(',', player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6) as players
from your_table;
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!